# Calling scope resolution-ed CPP function from Objective C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I have a cpp function defined in a dynamic library like this

```
namespace A
{
namespace B
{
    class C
    {
     public:
        static funcA();
    };
}
}
```

Now I am calling the above function from obcpp.mm file in the following manner:

```
void sample()
{
    A::B::C::funcA();
}
```

This gives me error like Undefined Symbol A::B::C::funcA

Would highly appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: Did you import the namespace?

Comment: I just included the header file that declares the whole thing.

Comment: I have seen it, however, it didn't resolve the issue

Comment: Hold on. Undefined symbol? What is the error message **verbatim**?

Comment: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
clang: error: linker command failed